# Overlaying a text box on a leaflet.js map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This might seem a very simple question, but I've searched elsewhere for the answer with no luck!

How do I overlay a simple text box on to a Leaflet map that loads when the map loads (not fixed to any point on a map) - for example, to give a title and more information within the actual map object. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two simple options, extend a new [`L.Control`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control) and place it in one of the four corners of the map window with content created inside the [`onAdd`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icontrol-onadd) method, or place a [`L.DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) anywhere on the map alongside a `L.Marker`, by either geographical coordinates or coordinates based upon the dimensions of the container.Making it "box" like would just include a small bit of CSS as you see fit, like some `padding`,`background-color`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was presuming some sort of Control method. Does this sound appropriate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316273/mapbox-map-styling-for-description-box/28319456#28319456

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but here's some sample code, CSS as necessary:

```js
L.Control.textbox = L.Control.extend({
  onAdd: function(map) {
   
  var text = L.DomUtil.create('div');
  text.id = "info_text";
  text.innerHTML = "<strong>text here</strong>"
  return text;
  },

  onRemove: function(map) {
   // Nothing to do here
  }
 });
 L.control.textbox = function(opts) { return new L.Control.textbox(opts);}
 L.control.textbox({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: This code works. Can you add an example how to update/change the text later?

Comment: Using jquery, $("#info_text")[0].innerHTML = 'new text'

Comment: This got me started, but I had Tyescript errors. See my answer below for a neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer from @Kyouma, the following is simpler and doesn't generate any TypeScript errors:

```
    let textbox   = L.Control.extend({
        onAdd: function() {
            
        var text = L.DomUtil.create('div');
        text.id = "info_text";
        text.innerHTML = "<h2>" + your text + "</h2>"
        return text;
        },

    });
    new textbox({ position: 'topleft' }).addTo(map);
```