# Do leaflet maps have a label function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Anyone know whether it is possible to add a label beside my markers on my react-leaflet map?

Comment: Just searching for "react-leaflet label" brought me to this result: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/291 ? Is this exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link FrankerZ sent you to is pretty helpful, definitely check that out.

If you mean a little popup label that shows up when you hover over a marker (or Polyline, etc.) then as of Leaflet 1.0, you can use [Tooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip). I've found that it works much more smoothly than making a Popup, and uses less code, especially if you're just opening the popup on hover. It might look like:

```
 var Marker = L.marker...
 Marker.bindTooltip('HI').openPopup();
```

And you can use the [permanent](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip-permanent) boolean flag if you want to keep it open.

A less popup-y option is [DivIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#divicon), if you want a text label that stays at a certain position always. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767463/overlaying-a-text-box-on-a-leaflet-js-map) SO post. Basically you can add a div that is associated with a geographical position, then format the div to look as text-y or text box-y as you want.